# GetEnumerator interface implementation

Tags: c#, foreach, interface, enumerator

I have this foreach loop where I am trying to go through a documentTables list of Table class which contains Table objects which contain Row class objects. Currently I am getting an error saying : foreach statement cannot operate on variables type test1.Table because it does not contain a public definition for GetEnumerator. I dont fully understand what is happening and not sure whats the best way to implement interface.

```
for (int i = 0; i < documentTables.Count(); i++)
{
   foreach (Row r in documentTables[i])
   { 
      // some functionality here
   } 
}
```

TABLE CLASS (Row class pretty much the same, has few strings and constructor):

```
class Table { 
public Row a; 
public Row b; 
public Row c;

public Table (Row _a,Row _b,Row _c)
 {
a=_a; 
b=_b; 
c=_c;

} 
}
```

Comment: If you want a row then you loop over rows, not over tables: _documentTables[i].Rows;_

Comment: You have to show your Table class, does it implement `IEnumerable<Row>` or just hold a collection that stores the rows? In that case use that property, f.e.: `foreach (Row r in documentTables[i].Rows)`

Comment: Do you have the implementation of table and row without it its hard to second guess

Comment: Show how  `Table` is implemented.

Comment: @Sweeper Table class has just Row variables and Constructor

Comment: So your Table class cannot have more than 3 rows? I really suggest you to use a `List<Row>` property instead. But why are you reinventing the wheel? What is missing in the Framework provided DataTable class that you need to build your own Table class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in

> The foreach statement repeats a group of embedded statements for each
>   element in an array or an object collection that implements the
>   [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=netframework-4.7) or [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.7) interface.

So your *Table* class needs to implement *IEnumerable*:

```
class Table: IEnumerable
{
    public Row a;
    public Row b;
    public Row c;

    public Table(Row _a, Row _b, Row _c)
    {
        a = _a;
        b = _b;
        c = _c;

    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return a;
        yield return b;
        yield return c;
    }
}


public class Row { }
```

Then you can do:

```
var myTable = new Table(new Row(), new Row(), new Row());
foreach (var row in myTable)
{
    // some functionality here
}
```

Another possible implementation of your Table class (more flexible, I think) is the following:

```
class Table: IEnumerable
{
    private Row[] _rows;

    public Table(params Row[] rows)
    {
        this._rows = rows;

    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var row in _rows)
        {
            yield return row;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the number of rows in the constructor is not limited to three.